# Authenticate everyone connects In Android WIFI HotSpot

Tags: android, authentication, android-wifi, android-networking

I wanna a create a app, which will ask user to enter his name and age when user connects to my wifi hotspot. Basically I wanna create a filter or firewall which will make sure all the request go through that before allowing the user to use internet.

Comment: Hmmm.. create `a background service` which monitors the wifi. **OR** Change the SSID of your Wifi Hotspot to the name of your app and then Create a way in your app that the user has to enter the following data to get the Password...

Comment: have you tried anything for now ?

Comment: @SyedAliNaqi Running background service won't help me in this case as I need events to which will can tell user has connected and intercept him every time he tries to access internet.
Can you tell me more about SSID solution, I am new to android wifi.

Comment: WHat i have in in mind is like that set the name of your Wifi Hotspot to like this: **Open MYAPP for pass** . Then in this app ask for the details u require and then after that give them the password....

Comment: I don't want user to install any app, but I can install as many apps I want in the device which will provide hotspot